# SSH private key: one location only?

Tags: ssh

Besides my personal computer, I use a number of devices exclusively: phone and tablet terminal apps, work laptop and various semi-retired rigs I keep to hand.

Naturally my SSH public key is propagated to authenticate on destination systems. But it's the full pair at my various starting points that's unclear.

May I give all these devices I venture out from a copy of my personal computer's key pair or is it better practice to generate a unique pair for my account on each system?

Comment: I've voted to close this question as "primarily opinion based", because the answer depends on your goals and your risk profile. [This article](https://blog.1password.com/ssh-security-practices-changing/) from the 1Password folks has some interesting thoughts on this question (disclaimer: I'm not a 1password user and haven't actually tried out the solution they present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, private keys, should be private and stored only on the workstation (device) you are connecting from.

Assuming you have multiple workstations and multiple servers: You should have as many private-public key pairs as you have workstations. Each workstation has a single private key. The public key is copied to all servers.

If some machine can play both roles (workstation and server) it would of course have public keys originated from other devices. And probably its own too, if you want to do `ssh 127.0.0.1`. But it still would have just one private key (its own).

Comment: This means every time I get a new device I have to propagate a new public key everywhere I ssh to. And you give no reason why I should do this.

Comment: @stark Because it's the way pubkey authentication works. Unless you want to stick with password authentication (which is less safe, and bears the burden of you having to remember a password for each server).

Comment: Good example. I don't create a different password for every device that I connect from, but I do create a different password for every website that I visit. With ssh I can put the same public key on every site I visit with no danger.

Comment: I saw this question was closed as it's been designated 'opinion based' so I'm unlikely to get a definitive answer! The 1Password article shared is indeed a good overview of the problem, which spurred me to ask in the first place...

Comment: ... with so many passwordless SSH users about, I was happy to mark the opinion offered as a safe answer. My personal quandary has been perfectly addressed. But yes certainly, risk beyond that advice can be responsibly calculated.